# OpenCV project crashes when applying histogram to black image

Tags: c++, opencv, colors

I am trying to troubleshoot a project that uses openCV. Somewhere, there is a histogram equalization - that crashes when the input image is pure black (or pure white or pure something).
I have been trying to troubleshoot the debug assertion failure that I get - "Expression: vector subscript out of range" - unsuccessfully. Note: the method does not use EqualizeHistogram, it creates the histogram manually, counts pixels per level, does an average - like in the textbook.
<strike>If I can isolate the case when I have a discrete color distribution - only one spike of color - I can just not do this optimization, and prevent the crash.</strike> So far the only situation the program is crashing is when the image histogram has only one value in one color, and 0 everywhere else.
<strike>How can I see how many colors are in my image ?</strike> 

Please help ! Thank you.
Edit: All I have to do is replace the method that doesn't work with the OpenCV method, cvEqualizeHistogram.

Comment: _How can I see how many colors are in my image?_ -- I would have thought a histogram would be ideal. Hehe. If you can reproduce this with a small program and test image, file a bug report -- it'll probably be fixed quickly if they can reproduce it instantly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience opencv is not well peer-reviewed and properly tested, which causes it to have strange behaviors in boundaries cases (I had some troubles with GrabCut). But as the function histogram has existed for long time, I doubt that it still has bugs. Maybe you are doing something wrong? Can you also reproduce the error if you have artificial mats of very small size? maybe 1x2?

Comment: Yes I created a custom image (not quite as small). I am editing my post to show that the code that I am trying to troubleshoot doesn't actually use cvEqualizeHistogram, it uses a few other OpenCV methods and manually does the equalization. So I will try to just use the EqualizeHistogram. Hope it works.